# Android Webview loads SPA web app but not equivalent linked web app

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have a strange problem and do not know where to start. I have an Android app that consists of a single WebView running a web app. The web app is in two equivalent forms: -

*Linked*: Usual web app with HTML that links to CSS, JavaScript, fonts, images, audio in separate files.

*Embedded*: Exactly the same web app but as a single HTML page, with the CSS and JavaScript included inline in the HTML file, and binaries added via Base64 data URLs.

The web app is served from the local Android file system using file URLs, and the directory structure is simple with the HTML in the home directory and everything else in a /res directory. I also put both forms of the web app on the Internet. Here is what happens: -

- Linked from Files = Fails, app is frozen and doesn't respond to user
  interaction.
- Linked from Internet = Works
- Embedded from Files = Works
- Embedded from Internet = Works

Below is the Android code that fails, and you can easily see how I change it to get the other versions.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- APP: BABYCLIX Test View File -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.babyclix.test_view">
    <!-- Uncomment if need Internet access
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BabyClix"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden">
        <activity android:name="com.babyclix.test_view.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.babyclix.test_view;
// APP: BABYCLIX Test View File

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
// MK>> BEGIN: Added these imports.
// For webview
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
// For immersive
import android.view.View;
// For screen handling on changes (eg. reorientation, resizing)
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
// MK>> END

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebview;

    // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // MK>> BEGIN: This is a webview app.
        mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // TO TEMPLATE
        mywebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
        // Allow access to files and file URLs.
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess();
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs();
        //webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs();
        // Allow audio on cover page without user action
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
            webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
            };
        // MK>> END

        // MK>> BEGIN: Select app source.
        // Set the URL to load.
        // Can be https:// or file://
        // https: Must enable Internet access in AndroidManifest.
        //mywebview.loadUrl("https://babyclix.fun/en/books/book_name/book.html");
        //mywebview.loadUrl("https://babyclix.fun/en/books/book_name/view.html");
        // file: Must put files/resources in /assets directory.
        // mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/book.html");
        mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/view.html");
        // MK>> END

        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    // MK >> To hide all bars and go into sticky immersive mode.
    // Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    // MK >> To handle screen changes.
    // Ref: 
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mywebview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
    // except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}
```

Can anyone see what would cause this strange behaviour? If the linked version can run from the Internet it should run from files, as proved by the embedded version.

Answer (score 1):

After that great long question I discovered the answer, all I needed to do was add the line

```
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
```